# How to fix memory leak in this program

Tags: c

On the below program, I need to call free() on Hash Table, List Elements and Unique words.  I tried couple things but all either break the program or increases error messages.  Some attempts are in comments and bold.

Does anyone know where and how to call free?  Its confusing as pointers are involved.

```
h_ptr *htable;
int tsize;


void new_table(int size)
{
    tsize = size;
    htable = (h_ptr *) calloc(size, sizeof(h_ptr));
    if (!htable) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate hash array, exiting\n");
    exit(1);
    }


    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
      {
    htable[i]=NULL;
      }
}
```

Comment: There's too much code in your question. Can you try skimming it?

Comment: we are not your debugger, pick a part and ask a specific question about it

Comment: Your question got closed (so I can't "answer") but skimming your code, I see what you're doing wrong. Two rules of thumb for you; first, each call to `malloc()` should have a matching call to `free()` second hold onto the memory as long as you need it. You have some function where you call malloc at the top and free at the bottom then return the pointer. No, that's bad. You pass the pointer back to the caller then the caller frees it when it's totally done.

Answer (score 2):

preventing memory leak is always the same. If you have allocated some memory dynamically delete it properly. So if your function uses `malloc()` somewhere also write `free()` somewhere to avoid memory leakage

Comment: Yeah, but every time I try it, it either breaks the program or gives me even more memory leaks errors (using Valgrind).  I am not sure where to call free and what syntax to use as pointers are involved. we are calling free() on Hash Table, List Elements and Unique words.     For example, where do I free "result" variable?

Comment: a pointer should be passed as argument of free. It can be pointer to anything. Actually the prototype is free(void*)

Comment: Yeah, I tried "free ((void *) htable);"(Second last line, and it adds even more memory leaks.)